# How can I do a partial update (i.e., get isolated changesets) from subversion with subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, changeset

If a file is committed several times with various changes, how can I fetch one change at a time, i.e., one changeset at a time?

I use eclipse, subversion, and subclipse, and I can't change the former two for the time being (or the MS platform..).

In my Team/Synchronization view in eclipse (using subclipse), choosing the changeset model, a file seems to be listed only in the latest relevant changeset even if all changesets are listed.  So an earlier changeset doesn't necessarily show the full set of files in the original commit, nor the original diff for a file in a commit.

Update: I'm thinking about using changesets for simplified code review, so I'd like the partial update represented for all the files commited in one changeset. It's easy to get diffs and specific revisions for specific files in eclipse, but I'd like to step through all the changes in one specific commit/ changeset in a practical manner.

Comment: What I want to do is related to cherry-picking in Git...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion does not support atomic changesets.

(Note: If anyone can prove me wrong, I'll happily switch accepted answer.)

I've compared Git and Subversion using TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN (and looked at what is possible on the command line).

With both Svn and Git I can update to a certain revision, or see and update to different versions of only one file at a time.

With both Tortoise clients can I see individual commits (revisions) from the repository and look at changes between a revision and the previous revision. (Note that I can't seem to do this in Eclipse, ref the question.)

Only with Git, however, can I update to or cherry-pick an isolated commit.  The closest I've seen to this functionality in Subversion is to [update to head and then revert a certain revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126320/subversion-cherry-picking) with a "subtractive merge"...

Test setup: make a project, check out or clone the project, make 2 separate commits to repository from elsewhere, including at least one file that is modified in both commits.
Then, with Git: fetch remote changes.
Then, with both Git and Subversion: look at the log.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know, `svn up` will by default grab the latest revision of the file.

However, you can use the `-r` parameter to `svn up` to grab a particular revision of a file.  So if you know a file was committed in revisions 5, 7, and 9, you could do this:

```
svn up -r5 myfile
svn up -r7 myfile
svn up -r9 myfile
```

I believe (but I don't have an installation of it in front of me) that Subclipse has a similar option, labeled something like "Update to Revision..."

Comment: Hi Nick, I should have specified that I meant on a regular basis, i.e., regular updates/ commits from other commiters.  Regarding specific files it's also possible to get a specific revision from the history view in eclipse.

Btw, I didn't find any generic setting regarding changesets for subclipse, but I know eclipse supports it with CVS...

Comment: @Ingvald I'm not sure I understand your question.  You just want to get a list of the files that were committed in a particular revision?

Comment: Yes, to begin with.  

Let's say my co-developers on a project have committed a handful of changes with several files each, some of them modifying the same files.  If I want to review those changes (in a simple way) I'd like to look at one change/ commit/ changeset at a time before I update.

It's much easier to understand what's going on in a change across multiple files if I can see the whole set of changes in a commit. 

It's like svn diff, only automatic, in GUI, across several files and from one revision (vs the last revision) at a time. 

I hope I make sense :)