# Updated Branches after Merging one branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using `SVN` as repository. We have the structure of

```
Trunk
   Branch 1
   Branch 2
   .....
```

We used to merge the branches into `Trunk` only after the features are implemented and tested quite well. So it will be a stable working implementation. `Branch 1` has its own features and implementation so do `Branch 2`..

Now `Branch 1` has certain features which will be required by `Branch 2` and vice versa.. So, what we will do is, merge those branches. 
Say for e.g merge `Branch 2 -> Branch 1`..

After resolving the conflicts, now the `Branch 1` will be loaded with all the features from `Branch 2`. But to make the `Branch 2` to be updated, now I copy all the Merged files from `Branch 1` and replace the existing files.. Because a `merge` will result in conflicts that I already resolved for `Branch 2 -> Branch 1` merging..

Is copying the only way or is there other any other standard approach available in `SVN` itself??

Also am used to `Tortoise SVN` client..

Answer (score 1):

Ok so branch1 and branch2 are children of trunk (branched but hopefuly not residing INSIDE the trunk directory like your diagram shows?)

The two branches are unique and different from each other because not only they have different names but also different (new) code/changes.

Now you want branch1 to get all changes that branch2 received?
And branch1 should get all changes from branch2?

You have to decide: Do you want continued separate development of your branches or do you want to reintegrate the work that has been done? You can not have both without cherrypicking.

If you succeed with what you tried and also what khmarbaise suggested in the end you would have multiple branches that have *all the same content*. Is that what you really want? Then merge down into the trunk and burry your branches.

If you want only certain features from branch1 and branch2 you should cherrypick merge them (select revisions you want manually).

See [Undoing specific revisions in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126320/subversion-cherry-picking) for example

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch IL from trunk than merge branch-1 into IL and after that merge branch-2 to IL and finally merge IL into trunk...The conflicts have to solved and you shouldn't copy files, cause conflicts in steps are indication that there are some parts which have to be harmonized.